# From vectors of objects return one object as reference

Tags: c++, c++20

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>


namespace ranges = std::ranges;

struct Model
{
    double next_event_time;
};

double timeit(int repeats, int items, std::function<void(int)> func)
{
    auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (auto i = 0; i < repeats; i++)
        func(items);
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto dur = (end - begin);

    auto total_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(dur);

    return total_time.count() / repeats;
}

std::vector<Model> generate_examples(int number)
{

    std::default_random_engine generator;

    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);

    std::vector<Model> models;

    for (auto i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        models.push_back(Model{.next_event_time = distribution(generator)});
    }

    return models;
}

Model& get_next_model(std::vector<Model> &models)
{
    ranges::sort(models, ranges::less{}, [](const Model &x) { return x.next_event_time; });

    return models[0];
}

Model& get_next_model2(const std::vector<Model> &models)
{
    // Error here 
    return ranges::min(models, ranges::less{}, [](const Model &x) { return x.next_event_time; });
}

void timeOne(int items)
{
    std::vector<Model> models = generate_examples(items);

    get_next_model(models);
}

void timeTwo(int items)
{
    auto models = generate_examples(items);
    get_next_model2(models);
}

int main()
{
    const std::string MS_UNIT = "[ms]";
    int items = 1000;
    int repeats = 10000;

    //std::cout << timeit(repeats, items, timeOne) << MS_UNIT << std::endl;
    std::cout << timeit(repeats, items, timeTwo) << MS_UNIT << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If i compile above code, i get

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Model&' to an rvalue
> of type 'std::ranges::range_value_t<const std::vector&>'

at `get_next_model2`

Why would I be getting that error?

I am using

1. `g++10.2`
2. Run using `g++ -std=c++20 file.cpp`

I need to

1. Find `next_model` from vector of `Model`s
2. Set that `next_model.next_event_time` to `0`

Before I returned as copy `Model get_next_model(std::vector<Model> &models)`.
But using this I was modifying `.next_event`time` of the copy.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm sorry and thank you could you move this comment as an answer to [the question i deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66522756/error-deduced-class-type-tuple-in-function-return-type?noredirect=1#comment117599090_66522756)please?

Comment: It was just for your benefit, you didn't need to undelete the question. I wasn't really prepared to write out a detailed explanation anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload of `std::ranges::min` that accepts an arbitrary range returns by value.  Because it returns a temporary value, you cannot bind a non-const lvalue reference to its return value.  Even if you could, that reference would be dangling as soon as `get_next_model2` returned.

Use [`std::ranges::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/min_element) instead.  `min_element` returns an iterator to the minimum value in a range.  Note that if you want to return a non-const reference from `get_next_model2` it will need to accept a non-const reference to your `std::vector`, since the elements of a `const` vector are all themselves `const`.

```
Model& get_next_model2(std::vector<Model> &models)
{
    return *ranges::min_element(
        models,
        ranges::less{},
        [](const Model &x) { return x.next_event_time; }
    );
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Pq3xE5)

Comment: If `models` is empty, dereferencing the returned value from `min_element()` gives undefined behaviour.    Better to check for that BEFORE dereferencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can not return a non-const Model reference from a `const vector<Model>`.  Make your return type `const Model&`  Or simply declare the `models` param in `get_next_model2` without the `const` keyword.

```
Model& get_next_model2(std::vector<Model> &models)
```

Or:

```
const Model& get_next_model2(const std::vector<Model> &models)
```