# error: deduced class type 'tuple' in function return type

Tags: c++, tuples, c++20

**What I am doing**

I am practicing c++ after 3 years. I needed to learn fast and broadly, so this example i am trying to solve might look odd to you.

I am using `c++20`, `gcc 10.2`.

I wanted to make a **pythonic enumerate function** that

- Takes any `container<T>`
- Yields `std::tuple<int, T>`
- Where `T` is the type of items in the container

I wanted to try applying **pythonic range** as an argument of `enumerate` which

- Takes `(int start, int end, int step)`
- Yields `int i` from `start` to `end` every `step`

**range** (Not my code, I only added `step` functionality)

```
template <typename T>
class range_iterator;

template <typename T>
class range_impl
{
    const T start_;
    const T stop_;
    const T step_;

public:
    range_impl(T start, T stop, T step) : start_{start}, stop_{stop}, step_{step} {};
    range_impl(T start, T stop) : start_{start}, stop_{stop}, step_{1} {};
    range_impl(T stop) : start_{0}, stop_{stop}, step_{1} {};

    range_iterator<T> begin() const
    {
        return range_iterator<T>{start_, step_};
    }

    range_iterator<T> end() const
    {
        return range_iterator<T>{stop_, step_};
    }
};

template <typename T>
class range_iterator
{
    T current_;
    const T step_;

public:
    range_iterator(T init, T step) : current_{init}, step_{step} {};

    range_iterator<T> &operator++()
    {
        current_ += step_;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(const range_iterator<T> &rhs) const
    {
        return current_ != rhs.current_;
    }

    T operator*() const
    {
        return current_;
    }
};

template <typename T>
range_impl<T> range(const T start, const T stop, const T step)
{
    return range_impl<T>(start, stop, step);
}

template <typename T>
range_impl<T> range(const T start, const T stop)
{
    return range_impl<T>(start, stop);
}

template <typename T>
range_impl<T> range(const T stop)
{
    return range_impl<T>(stop);
}
```

Can be used like following

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    for(auto i: range(0, 100 2)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Problem code: enumerate**

```
template <typename T>
class enumerate_iterator;

// Here, T should be a type of a container that contains type X 
template <typename T>
class enumerate_impl
{
    T impl;

public:
    enumerate_impl<T>(T impl) : impl{impl} {/* empty */};

    enumerate_iterator begin() const
    {
        return enumerate_iterator{impl.begin()};
    }

    enumerate_iterator end() const
    {
        return enumerate_iterator{impl.end()};
    }
};


// Here, T should be a type of a iterator, I think. Confused myself.
template <typename T>
class enumerate_iterator
{

    T iterator;
    int i;

public:
    enumerate_iterator(T iterator) : iterator{iterator}, i{0} {/* empty body */};

    enumerate_iterator<T> &operator++()
    {
        i++;
        iterator++;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(const enumerate_iterator<T> &rhs) const
    {
        return iterator != rhs.iterator;
    }

    std::tuple operator*() const
    {
        return {i, *iterator};
    }
};

template <typename T>
enumerate_impl<T> enumerate(T impl)
{
    return enumerate_impl<T>{impl};
}
```

Expected usage

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    for (auto &[i, j] : enumerate(range(0, 100, 2)))
    {
        std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Gotten error** (There actually tons of compilation error, but I want to try more on the others).

```
utility.cpp:186:20: error: deduced class type 'tuple' in function return type
  186 |         std::tuple operator*() const
```

I guessed this is complaining that `you didn't tell me what type the tuple contains`. But the thing is, I don't know what type `T iterator` contains. How would I tell `return type is std::tuple<int, type T contains>`?

Thanks for reading this long long question.

Comment: Whether it's your code or not, beware that's terrible code. It's not even a valid C++ range. There's no point in having iterators if you can't actually use them with anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think that perhaps, for `enumerate_iterator`, you might want its template type `T` to be a "base element type", not some compound "iteration type".

For example, if you were to choose to implement your iteration using raw memory pointers, then the `enumerate_iterator`'s data member called `iterator` would have type `T*` (instead of its current `T` type).

And then, in that case, the definition of `operator*()` would be programmed as having a return type of `std::tuple<int,T>`